# React Router | How to reset to Initial State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

Could you help me understand if the correct fix is React Router or React related?

**I'd like to be able to reset the state (not sure if this is the correct term), every time a user hits the same route again.**

I have a prototype that checks for either the *correct color* or the *correct cost* of a given car.

My **problem** as you'll see below, is that every time I hit the same route and/or my shuffle method. My list which controls the **state for show/hide** and **color** does not reset itself.

I've got separate routes rendering `<Cost/>` and `<Color/>` component

```
export const Routes = ({ state, shuffle }) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/car-cost"
      render={() => <Cost {...state} shuffle={shuffle} />}
    />
    <Route
      path="/car-color"
      render={() => <Color {...state} shuffle={shuffle} />}
    />
  </Switch>
);
```

I then pass the Routes into my main Parent Component. i.e:

```
// MAIN PARENT COMPONENT
export default class Dealership extends Component {
  state = {
    cars: [
      { name: "Ferrari", cost: "$9.000", color: "red", id: 1 },
      { name: "Porsche", cost: "$8.000", color: "black", id: 2 },
      { name: "lamborghini", cost: "$7.000", color: "green", id: 3 },
      { name: "McLaren", cost: "$6.000", color: "silver", id: 4 },
      { name: "Corolla", cost: "$50", color: "brown", id: 5 },
      { name: "Prius", cost: "$40", color: "beige", id: 6 },
      { name: "Saab", cost: "$30", color: "navy blue", id: 7 }
    ]
  };

  handleShuffle = () => {
    this.setState({
      cars: [...this.state.cars.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          <Routes
            state={this.state}
            shuffle={this.handleShuffle}
          />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

The example below shows the `<Cost />` component:

```
// QUESTION COMPONENT
const Question = ({ guess }) => <h1>What car is {guess}</h1>;

// COST COMPONENT
export default class Cost extends Component {
  render() {
    const { cars, shuffle } = this.props;
    const correctIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cars.length - 1));
    const correctCar = cars[correctIndex];

    const car = cars.map(car => (
      <CarList
        key={car.id}
        name={car.name}
        guess={car.cost}
        isCorrect={correctCar.cost === car.cost}
        greet={this.onGreet}
      />
    ));

    return (
      <>
        <Question key={correctCar.id} guess={correctCar.cost} />
        <button onClick={shuffle}>go again</button>
        <ul className="car-list">{car}</ul>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically, the Component above receives a list and that `<CarList/>` controls the **state to show and display color** if the **cost** of the car matches the one being asked on the `<Question />` component

```js
// CAR LIST COMPONENT
export default class CarList extends Component {
  state = {
    show: false
  };

  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };

  getColor = () => {
    if (this.state.show) {
      if (this.props.isCorrect) {
        return "green";
      } else {
        return "red";
      }
    }

    return "";
  };

  render() {
    const { name, guess } = this.props;
    const { show } = this.state;
    return (
      <li onClick={() => this.handleShow()} className={this.getColor()}>
        {name}
        <span className={show ? "show" : "hide"}>{guess}</span>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm handling the state for showing and controlling the colors inside of the `<Carlist/>` component so that each `<li/>` can listen to a click event and behave accordingly.

The issue as you can see also here on this [code sandbox][1]
is that any and every time I hit the same route or my `handleShufle()` method, the randomization happens accordingly but the `<CarList/>` state remains the same.

**How could I reset it back to its original state when clicking on the same link route?**